Could not find an option named "flavor"
Since Flutter 3.16, we now can read flavor passed through flutter run --flavor
on Flutter Web
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/134179
I tested it and it works. However, when I run in flutter build web --flavor banana I get Could not find an option named "flavor"
My question is: Is this pull request really just implement in Flutter Web development mode but not in the built release or I am missing something ? It's hard to believe, because what's the point of adding a feature that can't be deployed in production ?
